# Node.js MySQL insert issue

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Consider:

```
exports.adduser = function(connection) {
    return function(req, res) {

        // Get form values
        var username = req.body.username;
        var firstname = req.body.firstname;
        var lastname = req.body.lastname;

        var post = {
            username : username,
            firstname : firstname,
            lastname : lastname
        };

        connection.query('INSERT INTO myDatabase VALUES ?', post, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Are there any glaring issues? Is the syntax correct? When I press the submit button on my form, it just hangs, and the insert never occurs. I have confirmed that the form gets the right values. The fields in the database table are username, firstname, and lastname.

Comment: Did you try using `console.log` to see how far it gets? Does it even reach the query?

Comment: You are only sending a response when thee is an error - add an else in to send a success response

Comment: Yes, it is reaching the query. @KeepCalmAndCarryOn it wouldn't be spitting out the error response if it worked! :P

Comment: @TidusSmith That changes everything. Did you try outputting the **actual error** instead of a generic message?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You misread the manual! If you are using an object to `INSERT INTO` you need to use `SET`:

```
INSERT INTO myDatabase SET ?
```

[Quoting:](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values)

> If you paid attention, you may have noticed that this escaping allows you to do neat things like this:
>
> ```
> var post  = {id: 1, title: 'Hello MySQL'};
> var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
>   // Neat!
> });
> console.log(query.sql); // INSERT INTO posts SET `id` = 1, `title` = 'Hello MySQL'
> ```

Comment: `// get form values

        var post = {
            username : req.body.username,
            firstname : req.body.firstname,
            lastname : req.body.lastname
        };`