# Express.js not adding into mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm a beginner to ExpressJS, I want to be able to add records to the "site" table. However, when I run the following code, it says:

```
Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'BeastMode' in 'field list'.
```

"BeastMode" is an entry I made to the shortName field.

A little context: I'm not supposed to use ORM. I have to use raw sql queries to add to MYSQL database.I'm using 'mysql'package for Nodejs to connect to the database.

```
 var squery = "INSERT INTO SITE (shortName,addressLine1,addressLine2,city,state,zipcode,phoneNumber) VALUES "+
     "("+
      req.body.shortName+", "+
      req.body.addressLine1+", "+
      req.body.addressLine2+", "+
      req.body.city+", "+
      req.body.state+", " +
      req.body.zipcode+", " +
      req.body.phoneNumber+" );"    

     console.log(req.body);

     dbconnector.query(squery,function(err,rows,fields){
         if(!err){
             res.send("Record Added Successfully: "+req.body);
         }else{
             res.send("Error: "+ err);
         }
     });

    });
```

Also, here is my dbconnect.js file:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

dbconnect = mysql.createConnection({
 host: "localhost",
 user: "root",
 password: "",
 database:"rsacs"
});

module.exports = dbconnect
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <% include head %>
</head>
<body class="container">

<header>
   <% include header %>
</header>

<main>
   <div>
       <h1><%=title%></h1>
        <form method="post" action="/site/create" >
         <div class="form-group">   
            <label for="shortName">Shortname</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Shortname"  name="shortName"><br>

             <label for="Address Line 1"> Address Line 1:</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Address Line 1" name="addressLine1"><br>

             <label for="Address Line 2"> Address Line 2:</label>
             <input type="text"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Address Line 2" name="addressLine2"><br>

             <label for="City">City:</label>
             <input type="text"  class="form-control"  placeholder="City" name="city"><br>

             <label for="State">State:</label>
             <input type="text"  class="form-control"  placeholder="State" name="state"><br>

             <label for="Zipcode">Zipcode:</label>
             <input type="text"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Zipcode" name="zipcode"><br>

             <label for="PhoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
             <input type="text"  class="form-control"  placeholder="PhoneNumber" name="phoneNumber"><br>

             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
         </div>                                                            
       </form>
   </div>
</main>

<footer>
   <% include footer %>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

[Here is my Site table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MhBs.png)

Comment: Please see this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648667/nodejs-mysql-insert-issue?lq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I'd advise you to `console.log(squery)` and copy it from the logs and paste it into the `mysql console`. That will more clearly describe the error so that you could fix it. And also please update your post with what does `console.log(squery)` log and also error in the mysql console using the copied query.

Answer (score 1):

To echo @AnshumanJaiswal's solution, you're probably encountering an escape character problem.

The solution I'm going to propose, though, is different. The mysql nodejs driver [supports prepared queries](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#preparing-queries). As such, the most robust way to sort your query is:

```
var squery = "INSERT INTO SITE (shortName,addressLine1,addressLine2,city,state,zipcode,phoneNumber) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
var objs =  [req.body.shortName,req.body.addressLine1,req.body.addressLine2,req.body.city,req.body.state,req.body.zipcode,req.body.phoneNumber]
sql = mysql.format(squery, objs);
// now you have a properly-escaped SQL query which you can execute as usual:
connection.query(squery, objs, function (error, results, fields) {if (error) throw error;});
```

Let me know if this doesn't sort your problem.

Answer (score 0):

the values are string and you are not passing them as string. 
There are two possible ways:

**Solution 1.**

add `` to your string values like:

```
var squery = "INSERT INTO SITE (shortName,addressLine1,addressLine2,city,state,zipcode,phoneNumber) VALUES "+
     "('"+
      req.body.shortName+"', '"+
      req.body.addressLine1+"', '"+
      req.body.addressLine2+"', '"+
      req.body.city+"', '"+
      req.body.state+"', '" +
      req.body.zipcode+"', " +
      req.body.phoneNumber+" );"    
     ...
```

**Solution 2.**

make an object from body data as:

```
var data = {
    shortName: req.body.shortName,
    addressLine1: req.body.addressLine1,
    addressLine1: req.body.addressLine2,
    city: req.body.city,
    state: req.body.state,
    zipcode: req.body.zipcode,
    phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber
};
var squery = "INSERT INTO SITE SET ?";
dbconnector.query(squery, data, function(err,rows,fields){
     if(!err){
         console.log(rows);
         res.send("Record Added Successfully.");
     }else{
         res.send("Error: "+ err);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately both the solutions are throwing the following response:        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
       ^

TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
   at Query

Comment: can you log your query in console for 1st solution?

Comment: @PriyeshGoswami I have also updated my 2nd solution, `,` was missing in object. Sorry for that. I think now 2nd solution must work

Comment: @PriyeshGoswami also check your data in `body` I suspect you are sending `object` rather than `string`/`number` from client side.