# the data is not pushed into mysql table

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, mysql-error-1064

```js
connection.query("SELECT email, password FROM authenticate where email=?", email,
    function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      } else {
        if (result.length == 0) {
          console.log('name not available');
          res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/applyFailure.html"));
        } else if (result[0].password == password) {
          console.log(userData);
          connection.query("INSERT INTO userapplications SET ? ", userData,
            function (error, result, fields) {
              if (error){
                throw error;
              } 
              else{
                console.warn("insertion successful");
                res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/applySuccess.html"));
              }   
            });
        } else {
          console.log('invalid user and password');
          res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/apply.html"))
        }
      }
    });
  connection.end();
```

error:

> Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.

The database gets connected for some reason the data doesn't get added into the table.
I'm a beginner.

Comment: What is the value of `userData`?

Comment: its a simple object

Comment: `db connected
{
  education: 'BE in CSE/ISE',
  design: 'Artificial Inteligence (Python)',
  userView: '222'
}`

Comment: That should work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648667/node-js-mysql-insert-issue.

Comment: yeah. I'm not able to figure out.
I'm trying to query of a different table inside a query of a different table. Is this creating any kind of problem?
`

Comment: move your `connection.end();` inside your callback

Comment: @RohitAmbre Post an answer showing how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `connection.end();` inside callback like below.

```js
connection.query("SELECT email, password FROM authenticate where email=?", email,
    function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
        connection.end();
        throw error;
      } else {
        if (result.length == 0) {
          console.log('name not available');
          res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/applyFailure.html"));
        } else if (result[0].password == password) {
          console.log(userData);
          connection.query("INSERT INTO userapplications SET ? ", userData,
            function (error, result, fields) {
              if (error){
                connection.end();
                throw error;
              } 
              else{
                console.warn("insertion successful");
                res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/applySuccess.html"));
                connection.end();
              }   
            });
        } else {
          console.log('invalid user and password');
          res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/apply.html"))
          connection.end();
        }
      }
    });
  connection.end();
```

something like this, you can make changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of async nature of NodeJS. Try to concatenate the connection.end() with connection.query().

Like:

```
connection.query("your_code_here).end();
```

Comment: I'm not getting the error now, but I don't see anything inserted into my MySQL table :(

Comment: Actually it needs to be inside the callback function. Putting it there will still call it synchronously before the insertion.